# Can not execute script via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, travis-ci, amazon-ami, sshpass

I have remote machine and trying execute bash script to redeploy application after travis ci build is completed. I use `sshpass` to connect. But I cannot execute script.

```
echo "Starting deployment"
export SSHPASS=$PASSWORD
sshpass -e ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no deploy-user@deploy-server.com "bash /opt/redeploy.sh"
```

And after this I got `: No such file or directory` after travic ci deploy phase.
But when I trying to execute this command :

```
sshpass -e ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no deploy-user@deploy-server.com "touch /opt/myfile"
```

File successfully created. `redeploy.sh` is located in `/opt` directory and can be executed via terminal. But it can not be executed via this script.
Can anybody help me?

redeploy.sh has such content

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml pull
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: Perhaps use the full path to `bash` like `"/bin/bash /opt/redeploy.sh"` Also, if that doesn't work... is there anything in the `redeploy.sh` script that is pointing to a file using a relative path? Like does `redeploy.sh` work only if you are currently in `/opt`?

Comment: `redeploy.sh` has such content  `#!/bin/bash
echo "Running server redeploying"
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml pull
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d
echo "Completed deployment"`

Comment: `: No such file or directory` often means you have DOS newlines

Comment: Make sure your script has proper UNIX newlines (just `\n`, not `\r\n`). `dos2unix` is helpful for this.

Comment: `bash -x`, btw, is your friend (in terms of figuring out exactly what commands are being run). You might want to set it for both local and remote shell interpreters: `set -x` in your local script, `ssh ... "bash -x /opt/redeploy.sh"` when invoking the remote one

Comment: Charles Duffy Thanks is helped) The problem was in `\r\n)` in local machine

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).